# Did Arataka Reigen retain or unlock some psychic powers?

Tags: mob-psycho-100

At the end of the first season, Mob lent his powers to Arataka Reigen and after that he's able to see Dimple. Before when Mob's brother started to see Dimple, Dimple said this was because he was about to unlock his psychic powers. Did Arataka Reigen retain or unlock some psychic powers after Mob lent his powers to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, not really.

At the end of episode 12 of season 1, Reigen says that the only thing he gained from that experience was the ability to see Dimple now, and that aside from that, not much has changed.

[image: Screencap from season 1 episode 12 of Reigen chatting with Dimple]

Answer (score 2):

like Ritsu Kageyama the abilty to see dimple is the first of his psychic abilities then dimple helps training him by occasionally possesing him to stabilize his psychic out put. Eventually Ritsu was strong enough to decimate entire legions of claw members and if you watch the spirits and such consultation offices firs holiday. you will see at a specific time reigen has the ability to speed up while becoming intangible. Reference to when he had spent some time on the train and was going insane. Katsuya walks in and then Riegen activates his power unknowingly for a split second...